# TensorFlow Error when trying to run two Jupyter notebooks with tensorFlow code

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

I'm trying to run two Jupyter notebooks on Windows with TensorFlow code. When I run first notebook it runs successfully but when I try to run second notebook, without shutting down first notebook, it throws error. No code is running in first notebook when trying to run second notebook.

I open the Jupyter notebook by activating Tensorflow environment in Conda and then call jupyter notebook.

Error comes while running #Cell 4# of the code, If first notebook is shutdown
then second notebook runs without any error but #Cell 3# needs to run again before executing the Cell where error came (Cell 4)

```
            WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-6-0702350d4d1b>:4: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
            Instructions for updating:
            Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
            Initialized
            ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
               1021     try:
            -> 1022       return fn(*args)
               1023     except errors.OpError as e:

            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
               1003                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
            -> 1004                                  status, run_metadata)
               1005 

            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
                 65             try:
            ---> 66                 next(self.gen)
                 67             except StopIteration:

            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
                465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
            --> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
                467   finally:

            InternalError: Blas SGEMM launch failed : a.shape=(128, 784), b.shape=(784, 1024), m=128, n=1024, k=784
                 [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_0/_13, Variable/read)]]
                 [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_55_Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

            InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
            <ipython-input-6-0702350d4d1b> in <module>()
                 15         # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
                 16         feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
            ---> 17         _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                 18         if (step % 500 == 0):
                 19             print("Minibatch loss at step {}: {}".format(step, l))

            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
                765     try:
                766       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
            --> 767                          run_metadata_ptr)
                768       if run_metadata:
                769         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
                963     if final_fetches or final_targets:
                964       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
            --> 965                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
                966     else:
                967       results = []

            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
               1013     if handle is None:
               1014       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
            -> 1015                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
               1016     else:
               1017       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

            C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
               1033         except KeyError:
               1034           pass
            -> 1035       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
               1036 
               1037   def _extend_graph(self):

            InternalError: Blas SGEMM launch failed : a.shape=(128, 784), b.shape=(784, 1024), m=128, n=1024, k=784
                 [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_0/_13, Variable/read)]]
                 [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_55_Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

            Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
                "__main__", mod_spec)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
                exec(code, run_globals)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
                app.launch_new_instance()
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
                app.start()
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
                ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
                super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
                handler_func(fd_obj, events)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
                self._handle_recv()
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
                self._run_callback(callback, msg)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
                callback(*args, **kwargs)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
                return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
                handler(stream, idents, msg)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
                user_expressions, allow_stdin)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
                res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
                return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2683, in run_cell
                interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2787, in run_ast_nodes
                if self.run_code(code, result):
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2847, in run_code
                exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
              File "<ipython-input-5-356ef7c4c4f2>", line 21, in <module>
                logits_1 = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 1765, in matmul
                a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 1454, in _mat_mul
                transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
                op_def=op_def)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
                original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
              File "C:\Users\Auro\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
                self._traceback = _extract_stack()

            InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas SGEMM launch failed : a.shape=(128, 784), b.shape=(784, 1024), m=128, n=1024, k=784
                 [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_0/_13, Variable/read)]]
                 [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_55_Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Below is the code:

```
            # These are all the modules we'll be using later. Make sure you can import them
            # before proceeding further.

            #CELL 1#
            from __future__ import print_function
            import numpy as np
            import tensorflow as tf
            from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
            from six.moves import range

            pickle_file = 'notMNIST.pickle'

            with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
              save = pickle.load(f)
              train_dataset = save['train_dataset']
              train_labels = save['train_labels']
              valid_dataset = save['valid_dataset']
              valid_labels = save['valid_labels']
              test_dataset = save['test_dataset']
              test_labels = save['test_labels']
              del save  # hint to help gc free up memory
              print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
              print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
              print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)

            image_size = 28
            num_labels = 10

            #CELL 2#

            def reformat(dataset, labels):
              dataset = dataset.reshape((-1, image_size * image_size)).astype(np.float32)
              # Map 0 to [1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ...], 1 to [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ...]
              labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
              return dataset, labels
            train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
            valid_dataset, valid_labels = reformat(valid_dataset, valid_labels)
            test_dataset, test_labels = reformat(test_dataset, test_labels)
            print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
            print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
            print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)

            def accuracy(predictions, labels):
                return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
                        / predictions.shape[0])





            #CELL 3#

            num_nodes= 1024
            batch_size = 128


            graph = tf.Graph()
            with graph.as_default():

                # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
                # at run time with a training minibatch.
                tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
                tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
                tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
                tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

                # Variables.
                weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, num_nodes]))
                biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_nodes]))
                weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_nodes, num_labels]))
                biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))

                # Training computation.
                logits_1 = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1
                relu_layer= tf.nn.relu(logits_1)
                logits_2 = tf.matmul(relu_layer, weights_2) + biases_2
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_2, labels=tf_train_labels))

                # Optimizer.
                optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

                # Predictions for the training
                train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits_2)

                # Predictions for validation 
                logits_1 = tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1
                relu_layer= tf.nn.relu(logits_1)
                logits_2 = tf.matmul(relu_layer, weights_2) + biases_2

                valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits_2)

                # Predictions for test
                logits_1 = tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_1) + biases_1
                relu_layer= tf.nn.relu(logits_1)
                logits_2 = tf.matmul(relu_layer, weights_2) + biases_2

                test_prediction =  tf.nn.softmax(logits_2)



            #CELL 4#

            num_steps = 3001

            with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
                tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
                print("Initialized")
                for step in range(num_steps):
                    # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
                    # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
                    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
                    # Generate a minibatch.
                    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
                    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
                    # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
                    # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
                    # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
                    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
                    _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
                    if (step % 500 == 0):
                        print("Minibatch loss at step {}: {}".format(step, l))
                        print("Minibatch accuracy: {:.1f}".format(accuracy(predictions, batch_labels)))
                        print("Validation accuracy: {:.1f}".format(accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels)))
                print("Test accuracy: {:.1f}".format(accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels)))
```